# Selenium Multiple window with else part

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can I use

```
if(!MainWindow.NotEqualsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow))
```

in the `else` part to prompt that the entered id is wrong?

If I can, why do I get an error?

Does the method `MainWindow.NotEqualsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow))` have valid syntax or not?

Comment: Which language binding art?

Comment: what do u mean?